# Scala/Spark Apriori implementation extremely slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are trying to implement the [Apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) in Scala using Spark (you don't need to know the algorithm to answer this question).

The function computing the itemsets of the Apriori algorithm is `freq()`. The code is correct but it gets slower after each iteration in the `while` in the `freq()` function, up to the point of taking several seconds to perform a cross join on a table with 1 row with itself.

```
import System.{exit, nanoTime}
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, SparkSession, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

object Main extends Serializable {
  val s = 0.03

  def loadFakeData() : DataFrame = {
    var data = Seq("1 ",
                   "1 2 ",
                   "1 2",
                   "3",
                   "1 2 3 ",
                   "1 2 ")
                .toDF("baskets_str")
                .withColumn("baskets", split('baskets_str, " ").cast("array<int>"))
      data
  }
  
  def combo(a1: WrappedArray[Int], a2: WrappedArray[Int]): Array[Array[Int]] = {
    var a = a1.toSet
    var b = a2.toSet
    var res = a.diff(b).map(b+_) ++ b.diff(a).map(a+_)
    return res.map(_.toArray.sortWith(_ < _)).toArray
  }
  val comboUDF = udf[Array[Array[Int]], WrappedArray[Int], WrappedArray[Int]](combo)

  def getCombinations(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.crossJoin(df.withColumnRenamed("itemsets", "itemsets_2"))
      .withColumn("combinations", comboUDF(col("itemsets"), col("itemsets_2")))
      .select("combinations")
      .withColumnRenamed("combinations", "itemsets")
      .withColumn("itemsets", explode(col("itemsets")))
      .dropDuplicates()
  }

  def countCombinations(data : DataFrame, combinations: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
    data.crossJoin(combinations)
      .where(size(array_intersect('baskets, 'itemsets)) === size('itemsets))
      .groupBy("itemsets")
      .count
  }

  def freq() {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("FreqItemsets")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    // data is a dataframe where each row contains an array of integer values
    var data = loadFakeData()
    val basket_count = data.count

    // Itemset is a dataframe containing all possible sets of 1 element
    var itemset : DataFrame = data
                                .select(explode('baskets))
                                .na.drop
                                .dropDuplicates()
                                .withColumnRenamed("col", "itemsets")
                                .withColumn("itemsets", array('itemsets))
    var itemset_count : DataFrame = countCombinations(data, itemset).filter('count > s*basket_count)
    var itemset_counts = List(itemset_count)

    // We iterate creating each time itemsets of length k+1 from itemsets of length k
    // pruning those that do not have enough support
    var stop = (itemset_count.count == 0)
    while(!stop) {
      itemset = getCombinations(itemset_count.select("itemsets"))
      itemset_count = countCombinations(data, itemset).filter('count > s*basket_count)
      stop = (itemset_count.count == 0)
      if (!stop) {
        itemset_counts = itemset_counts :+ itemset_count
      }
    }

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the algorithm itself is notably inefficient: `O(2^d)` (where `d` is the number of items in at least one basket).  I haven't used spark in a while, but I wonder if the `DataFrame`s are getting recomputed anew each time through (in which case caching `itemset` might help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Spark retains the right to regenerate datasets, at any time, that may be what's happening, in which case caching the results of expensive transformations can lead to dramatic improvements in performance.

In this case, it looks at first glance like `itemset` is the heavy hitter, so

```
itemset = getCombinations(itemset_count.select("itemsets")).cache
```

May pay dividends.

It should also be noted that building up a list by appending in a loop is generally a lot slower (`O(n^2)`) than building it by prepending.  If correctness isn't affected by the order of `itemset_counts`, then:

```
itemset_counts = itemset_count :: itemset_counts
```

will produce at least a marginal speed-up.